# common thirdparty libraries like Money in onuon architecture

Tags: architecture

во є приклаж зверху є messageIn onion architecture, we have a core that includes an `application` layer as an outer layer of the core and a `domain` layer as an inner layer of the core. Also, we have `presentation`, `infra` layers as an onion skin (layers above the core).
Inner layers should not use concepts of outer layers but should have interfaces (ports) that can be implemented by outer layers.

But what about common libraries like Money or some DateTime libraries, is that mean I need to make an interface in the `domain` layer and implement that interface? I mean those libraries are like generic helpers and it seems like a time waste of making adapters on top of those libraries. But on another side, I understand that core should be independent. So I'm not sure if I can break a rules and do not create ports/adapters for those libraries or I SHOULD create them? Are there any best practices, or proposals, ideas from your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My view on this is that it's quite difficult (aka impossible) that a class in a third party library maps 1-1 with your Domain.

The `Money` class your library has might well have much more functionalities than really needed. I would honestly create a wrapper in my Core project.

Keep in mind that the goal is to represent the Domain as much as clearly and easily possible, with the least number of "distractions" possible. A third-party library will for sure expose methods and properties you might never use (and maybe you don't want anyone else to use).

Comment: I agree but in my practice, most of such libraries will never replaced with others, for example, https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ , this DateTime library has awesome helper methods and it's mean you always need to make an interface and adapter and periodically extend with new functionality (which already exists in the library) to feet new domain requirements. 

I agree that in most cases it's a good idea to have an interface and adapter, but in the case of libraries like this I have a feeling that I'm just wasting the time creating a wrapper because the functionality is too common

Comment: and yeah, probably Money is not a good example, I can agree that money probably should be implemented with an adapter

Comment: true. In most of the cases, things like DateTime can be treated as base types. Domain-related classes like Money instead are too tied to the project :)

But still, don't trust too much external libraries!